# Multiplicity constraint violated. The role '' of the relationship '' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a Tab object. This Tab object has many Questions. Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class Tab
{
    /// <summary> init default values </summary>
    public Tab()
    {
        // Do some init stuff
    }
    public int ID { get;set; }

    //...

    /// <summary> Question for this Tap. Like Quiz-App or Sweepstake </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Tabs.Question> Questions { get; set; }

    //...
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual Tab Tab { get; set; }
 }
```

And here is the configuration for both classes.

```
class TabConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tab>
{
    public TabConfig()
    {
        this.Map(m => m.Requires("AppType").HasValue<byte>((byte)ApplicationType.Application)).ToTable("TmTabs");
        this.HasKey(c => c.ID);
        this.Property(p => p.ID).HasColumnName("ID").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    }
}

public class QuestionConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Question>
{
    public QuestionConfig()
    {
        ToTable("TmQuestions");
        HasKey(q => q.Id);
        Property(q => q.Id).HasColumnName("Id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(q => q.OrderNumber).HasColumnName("OrderNumber").IsRequired();
        Property(q => q.Text).HasColumnName("Text").IsRequired();
        HasRequired(q => q.Tab).WithMany(t => t.Questions).Map(q => q.MapKey("TmTabs_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

And the configuration will be added to the built event like this.

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{

    public Guid ContractId { get; set; }

    #region construction

    public ModelContext()
        : base(Tools.DatabaseTools.GetDefaultConnectionString())
    {
        ContractId = Guid.Empty;
    }

    public ModelContext(Guid contractGuid)
        : base(Tools.DatabaseTools.GetConnectionString(contractGuid))
    {
        ContractId = contractGuid;            
    }

    public ModelContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        ContractId = Guid.Empty;
    }

    public ModelContext(string connectionString, Guid contractGuid)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        ContractId = contractGuid;
    }


    public DbSet<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }     
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        // tab-table
        builder.Configurations.Add(new TabConfig());


        // Qustions
        builder.Configurations.Add(new ModelConfig.QuestionConfig());


        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```

On my Edit-Form I bind the whole Tab object to a binding Source and I edit some property of the Tab object and I add Questions.

If I save the Tab object the first time everything works fine. But if I edit the tab object I got this error:

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Question_Tab_Target' of the relationship 'Tabmaker.Common.Question_Tab' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

The code for the Tab business layer is:

```
public bool SaveTab<T>(ModelContext context, T tab) where T:Tab
    {
        try
        {
            // add if detached
            if (tab.ID == 0)
            {
                // new tab code
            }


            // attach/set to be modified if id!=0. if tab is not detached, the property 
            // changes were already tracked and nothing need to be done here
            var state = context.Entry(tab).State;
            if (state == EntityState.Detached || state == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                context.Entry(tab).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Catch
    return false
        }
    }
```

The error occurs if I ask for the state of the tab-entity:

```
var state = context.Entry(tab).State;
```

I hope I explained everything as good as possible.